# How to take an array list created by a scanner and call it?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, java.util.scanner

> I apologize for any confusion in my wording beforehand.

Okay so, I'm running into a problem with a new project I've been working on for my Computer Science course. This problem being that, I need to call an array list of strings created by user input(scanner) and display it in a template class. This template being in my base class and not the wrapper.

> Think asking someone for their opinions on something and then plugging those into a form that reads much nicer than a simple array list.

Here's a sample of the code I've been trying to no avail;

Template;

```
    public void RecipeDisplay(){
Recipe displayMethod = new Recipe(directions, recipeName, Determiner);
System.out.println("======================");
System.out.println("Recipe; " + displayMethod.getRecipeName());
System.out.println("======================");
System.out.println("Ingredients; " + displayMethod.getIngred());
System.out.println("Directions; " + displayMethod.getDirections());
System.out.println("Method Cooked; " + displayMethod.getDirections());
 }
```

Ingred being the array list of strings.

As for what I do when creating a recipe, I just use the .add Method. How can I take the Ingredients that I add to an instance of the list and then display it like in the template.

It appears blank when i run it.

> Please ask me for clarification if needed

Comment: What does one of these `get` methods currently look like?

Comment: What does method `getIngred()` return?

Comment: You can't "call" a List of Strings. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to display elements of the ArrayList in a more convenient way you have practically 2 options.

1 . implement a helper method which iterates through the `ArrayList` and composes a nicer `String` e.g.

```
private String composeIngredients(List<String> ingredients) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String ingredient : ingredients) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append(", ");
        }
        sb.append(ingredient);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

and use the method in the template

```
System.out.println("Ingredients; " + composeIngredients(displayMethod.getIngred()));
```

2 . Create a new class e.g. `MyArrayList` which extends `ArrayList` and which you use instead of the original `ArrayList`. Then override in that class the `toString()` method to have very similar body as the method above. This however seems to me like an overkill for what you want to achieve so I won't elaborate on this further unless you really want.